# cdc with python and merge on bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have written a pipeline using Apache beam and Google dataflow that sends changes from a MongoDB to bq. I have a bigquery log table like ...

| table | operation type | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [all columns] | [insert / update / delete / replace] | timestamp |

and a "normal" table without the operation and timestamp column. My goal is to merge the src table (log) and the target table. The problem is as following, when the second last entry to a field is not null and the last one is, how can I check this in the merge statement? For example in other databases you can do something like

```
create function get_sec_last_value(id) as (
  (
    select as struct
      *
    from (
      select
        *,
        row_number() over(order by timestamp desc) as number
      from table
      where id = id
    ) where number = 2
  )
);

merge target trg
using source as src
on trg.id = src.id

...
update set id = case 
    when (get_sec_last_value(src.id).id is not null and src.id is not null) or (get_sec_last_value(src.id).id is null and src.id is not null) then src.id
    when (get_sec_last_value(src.id).id is not null and src.id is null) or (get_sec_last_value(src.id).id is null and src.id is null) then null
    end
...
```

Has anybody faced the same problem or has an idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you following this bigquery [merge statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement)? if yes then can you be a bit more specific on the issue you are facing while implementing the same? Can you provide some sample data of both tables you want to merge?

Comment: Yea I was following that merge documentation. But I found out that it is only possible to merge 1:1 and not 1:N. So i have to solve the problem in a diffrent way. If I have a 1:1 mapping the old value does not matter anymore.  i have a id in the main table and n rows to that value in the log table and i wanted to merge them row by row at in the end the main table did all updates from the log table to get the current state of that row.

table a is like 
id | value 1 | value 2
1 |     x      |    y

log table like 
1 | null | x
1 | a| b
1 | null | c

after merge main table
1 | a | c

Comment: Please update the question, reading table values from the comment is difficult.